# Count function using two columns in sql table

Tags: sql, count, amazon-athena, presto, trino

[PICTURE OF SQL TABLE PLEASE LOOK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXqRv.png)

I'd like to count the number of uris that have xml in it for each request_ip, so id like the results table to look like this

```
| Request ip | Number of hits |
| 34.212.134 | 37298191       |
```

This is the query I tried but it didn't work

```
SELECT request_ip 
FROM "default"."www-live-lon-cf" 
COUNT (uri)
WHERE date>=date('2022-08-20')
AND date<=date('2022-10-31')
AND uri LIKE '%.xml'
group by request_ip
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and share data as text not image so it can be easy to help

Comment: _" it didn't work"_ - how exactly it didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to place `count` into the select statement:

```sql
SELECT request_ip, COUNT(*) hit_count
FROM "default"."www-live-lon-cf" 
WHERE date>=date('2022-08-20')
AND date<=date('2022-10-31')
AND uri LIKE '%.xml'
group by request_ip
```

If you want "human-readable" column names you can use double quotes for them:

```sql
SELECT request_ip as "Request ip", COUNT(*) as "Number of hits"
```